# Problema com Docker instalação pdo

Tags: pdo, docker

Pessoal estou com um problema com meus contêineres no docker, estava tentando levantar um Lamp com docker compose, com a imagem padrao do php:apache e do mysql, mas quando instalo o PDO aparece esse erro.

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

https://github.com/AurinoJunior/Lamp-Docker-with-pdo

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM php:apache

RUN apt-get update && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

COPY ./app /var/www/html/
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3"
services:
  php-apache:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8080:80"
    links:
     - dbmysql
    volumes:
     - ./app:/var/www/html

  dbmysql:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Ficarei grato a qualquer resposta !!!

Aurino Junior

Comment: Cara. Primeiro, coloque o código aqui e não o link.
Eu olhei lá... Substitua o `RUN apt-get update && \ `por  `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ ` Testa isso. Não esqueça de complentar o restante ...`&& docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql `

Comment: Beleza cara da proxima vez publico os codigos, obrigado por arrumar o post, vou tentar como você sugeriu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitua o `RUN apt-get update && \` por `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \` Acrescente logo depois `&& docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql`

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM php:apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

COPY ./app /var/www/html/
```

Neste link(https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-4-new-default-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password/) você poderá ler sobre o que está acontecendo com sua conexão recusada.

Caso não seja assim tão necessário usar a versão 8, faça o downgrade para versão 5. Então siga o seguinte.
Delete seu volume mysql local:

```
$ docker-compose down
$ sudo rm -r mysql/
```

Use um usuário e senha de desenvolvedor(*dev, dev123*), esqueça o root. 
Porém, você pode usar o root, ou se precisar para pegar a senha de root que será gerada randomicamente. Vá no terminal, quando o MySQL estiver sendo levantado e busque a senha gerada. A linha de log será mais ou menos assim: `dbmysql_1     | GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: odut5doo2ahngie5shohV8Eingah7us4`

Faça assim no seu *docker-compose.yml*, mudando a versão do Mysql(image: mysql:5), definindo o banco, random para senha de root e criação do usuário *dev*.

```
version: "3"
services:
  php-apache:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8081:80"
    links:
     - dbmysql 
    volumes:
     - ./app:/var/www/html

  dbmysql:
    image: mysql:5
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_USER: dev
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: dev123
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Agora rebuild no ambiente.  Se no seu ambiente for preciso, rode os comandos como admin, use: `sudo`

```
$ docker-compose up --build
```

No seu *config.php*, use o usuário dev, ou use o root:

```
<?php

    $dsn = "mysql:host=dbmysql;dbname=database";
    $dbuser = "dev";
    $dbpass = "dev123";


    try{
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn,$dbuser, $dbpass);
        echo "Conectado!";

    }catch (PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Continua com o mesmo erro SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory, sera que é algo relacionado a permissão da pasta mysql.

Comment: @AurinoJr Você realmente precisa da última versão do MySQL (8.0.11)? Há um problema com Default Authentication Plugin : caching_sha2_password. Vou editar Minha resposta com uma solução. Daí você testa.

Comment: Obrigado Fabiano deu certo agora, tava uns 3 dias batendo cabeça tentando resolver isso kkk vlw mesmo, posso commitar essa sua solução no meu github ?

Comment: @AurinoJr Eu estava subindo as alterações. Mas acho que vc já alterou

Comment: Alterei só a porta e o nome da database e esta tudo normal obrigado novamente :D